# T-SQL joining external variables into tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've come from an application dev and been thrust into the web dev and I'm getting my head around asymmetrical data requests/returns and how to handle them.

I need to make a number of SQL requests and though the best way to manage which ones are returned would be to insert a UUID or something similar into the return sql table.

Also, in general I'm pretty basic with my sql language, but I want to add an external value into my returned table, where @ext would be the external data added in from the original request.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    @ext AS uuid,
    dbo.Orders
WHERE ....
```

expected return table

```
uuid:  12234
customer: jack
orderNo: 774
postAddy: 123 Albert St
...
```

The error I'm always getting is "but declare the table variable "@ext".

Is this the right approach or am I just doing something dumb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you are getting is telling you that you haven't declared the table variable `@ext`.  This is because you've used a variable name (with the `@` prefix) in the `FROM` clause where it's expecting a table or other table-like object (ie. table, view, table variable, TVF, etc).

The `@ext` variable appears to be a scalar (single-valued) variable, so it isn't recognised in the `FROM` clause.  You should try something like this instead:

```
SELECT 
    -- scalar values and column names / aliases go here
    @ext AS uuid, *
FROM        
    -- only tables, views, table variables, TVF's etc go here
    dbo.Orders
WHERE ....
```

Note that if your query returns multiple rows, they will all have the same value for `uuid`.  This may or may not be desirable, and there may be better ways to achieve what you want, in terms of managing the data that is returned from multiple queries, but this is best posed in another question once you have a working example.

Comment: code is correct, but the explanation seems somewhat confused to me. A table variable **is** a variable - it's just has a non-scalar data type. +1 anyway.

Comment: @ZoharPeled yeah you're right, it wasn't worded very well.  I'll tidy it up a bit.

Comment: @pcdev your edited version is better to read yeah, but your original was enough for me to work out what I was doing wrong.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you know what `@ext` is for you and how to properly reference it.

If it's a sacalar value you can use it on expressions:

```
DECLARE @ext INT = 5

SELECT
    @ext AS ScalarValue,
    @ext + 10 AS ScalarOperation,
    @ext + S.SomeColumn AS ScalarOperationWithTableColumn
FROM
    SomeTable AS S
```

If it's a table variable, you can reference it as table (as in your example):

```
DECLARE @ext TABLE (
    FirstValue INT,
    SecondValue VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @ext (
    FirstValue,
    SecondValue)
VALUES
    (10, 'SomeText'),
    (20, 'AnotherText')

SELECT
    E.FirstValue,
    E.SecondValue
FROM
    @ext AS E
/*
    LEFT JOIN ....
WHERE
    ....
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for this EzLo, a very fleshed out answer.  I'm sure this will be useful later down the road. Cheers